# UDP connection with iPerf3

Tags: tcp, udp, connection, buffer, iperf3

My question is the following:

I'm doing some tests between 1 Access Point (AP) and 1 Client, so the connection is over wifi 2.4GHz 802.11 g.

At client side i have 2 PCs like at the AP side. I have a client-server connection and 2 VLAN for divide the traffic.

The PCs which are connected to the AP are rhe servers meanwhile the others are the client.

Server:

Server 1 - VLAN 2: .\iPerf3.exe -s

Server 2 - VLAN 3: .\iPerf3.exe -s

Client:

Client 1 - VLAN 2: .\iPerf3.exe -c <IP.server_1> -t 600 -u -b 10M

Client 2 - VLAN 3: .\iPerf3.exe -c <IP.server_2> -t 600 -u -b 10M

then i used to save the output of the servers in file.csv

when i put the "Bandwidth" in a graph i can see that the bandwidth isn't costant but it varies from 12 to 17 Mbps. These are the max bandwidths that can permit 0 packets loss.

So i have 0% packets loss but an unstable throughput, while if i use, for example: -b 5M for both clients, i still have 0% of packets loss and a stable throughput (14.8-15.2 Mbps).

Is this difference releted to the buffer size of my PCs?